# Why Xcode is reopened instead of launching application?

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I have reinstalled Xcode 7, and just downloaded an project (clang formatter) from github, and when I try to launch app, it does not launch it, but reopen Xcode. Put a break point into `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method, not get reached. Any idea why?

GIF show effect with [Clang-Format](https://github.com/travisjeffery/ClangFormat-Xcode) plugin, but Xcode has same behaviour with other projects too, like with [Alcatraz](https://github.com/supermarin/Alcatraz)

[image]

Comment: It's an xcode plugin, so I guess it needs xcode to work?

Comment: don't understand, I am running it from Xcode

Comment: The first 'clang formatter' on github I find is an XCode plugin, which means it only runs within xcode. By not telling us **what github project it is** we have no idea what's going wrong.

Comment: added link, but it is not relating one specific project or plugin, because Xcode has the same behaviour with any OSX based project, or plugin based project.

Comment: Again, in order to *run* something that creates an `.xcplugin` requires it to be hosted in xcode, so it **always launches xcode** when you choose 'run'. You've pointed to two projects that are `.xcplugin` types. Does it happen with a newly created OSX application project?

Comment: I have just downloaded both projects from github, `clang format` has been developed for a while, so it is not a newly created project I guess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93801/discussion-between-petesh-and-janos).